# Unity Timestamps warnings and Asset Errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

after updating Unity to the newest Version i get these errors when starting the Engine:

[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpGu8.png)

I took some help for fixing it. But when i delete the Lib Folder the Errors still come up. I created a new Project but even then the Errors come up after creating it and saving the first scene.

It just started with the new Update to 5.5 ..

Does anyone got some advise?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing the Asset Serialization under Editor Settings -> Asset Serialization.

I had to switch back from Force Text to Mixed.

That helped.